# How to fix 'float' object is not iterable?

Tags: python

I write a function `phix` that is input a `x` and `N`, then get a summation `x_new`.

```
def phix(x, N):
  lam=np.floor(N**(1/3))
  x_new=0
  for i in range(0, int(lam)):
   if (i+1)*N**(-1/3)>x>i*N**(-1/3):
    x_new=x_new+(2*i+1)/(2*N**(1/3))
  return x_new
```

Here is a error:

```
N=1
x = np.random.random_sample(N)
x_new=phix(x, N)
x_val = np.array(list(Counter(x_new).keys()))
```

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

In fact, I want to input `N=2` or `N=3` and `phix(x, N)` return a vector of `x_new` not a value. I am not sure how to do that? I try the following code but it seems does not work.

```
def phix(x,N):
  lam=np.floor(N**(1/3))
  x_new=np.zeros(N)
  for i in range(0, N):
    x_newa=0
    for j in range(0, int(lam)):
      if (j+1)*N**(-1/3)>x[i]>j*N**(-1/3):
        x_newa=x_newa+(2*j+1)/(2*N**(1/3))
    x_new[i]=x_newa
  return(x_new)
```

I do the following example.

```
N=3
x = np.random.random_sample(N)
x_new=phix(x,N)
print(x_new)
```

But it shows all same values

> [0.34668064 0.34668064 0.34668064]

Comment: You should look at what `phix` actually returns, and think about why it's not what you are expecting.

Comment: Right.  `phix` returns one thing.  What are you expecting that `array/list/Counter` line to do?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes! But can I return an array? I am confused how to modify `phix`.

Comment: You can do `np.array` over a single item, but `Counter` requires an iterable. You could put your summation into a list and then count it but... a summation will always produce a single number, and the output of `Counter(iterable_new_x)[keys]` is going to be that single number. Are you sure this is exactly what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: `phix` is computing a sum over `x`.  Is that not what you wanted?  You can certainly return an array, but an array of what?

Comment: @TimRoberts For example, `N=2`. I want to return two `x_new`. Can we modify `phix` to do that?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly No. I want to choose `N` larger than 2. So I need to modify `phix` to return a vector of `x_new`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I add a modified version of `phix` to return an array. But it returns the same values.

Comment: Have you done the math by hand here?  You will ONLY get either 0 or 0.34668.  With N=3, `lam` will be 1, so your inner loop will run exactly once.  Your computation of `x_newa` does not use the input `x` array at all.  It is only using `N` and `j`, so the only question is whether the `if` statement assigns 0 or 0.34668.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you! I want to write this summation inside the loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006898/how-to-make-sure-x-is-in-the-interval-between-in-1-3-and-i1n-1. I am not sure if the current for loop is right. Can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I don't know why you have two loops in there.  There only needs to be one loop, running from 0 to cube-root(N).  The function should accept one value (x) and return one value.  The value being added does not depend on x at all - x is only used to determine whether an element of the summation is included or not.

So, I believe this produces the result you want.  For each of your random values of x, there is one result.  And as I said, when N is 3, the inner loop only runs once, so the result can ONLY be 0 or 0.34668.  When N=1000 there is a bit more variation, but there are still only 10! possible results.

```
import numpy as np

def phix(x,N):
    ncr = N**(1/3)
    lam = int(ncr)
    sumx = 0
    for i in range(lam):
        if i/ncr < x < (i+1)/ncr:
            sumx += (i+i+1) / (2*ncr)
    return sumx

N = 1000
x = np.random.random_sample(N)
for x1 in x:
    print( x1, phix(x1,N) )
```

Output (truncated):

```
0.16252465361984203 0.15000000000000002
0.6527047022599177 0.6500000000000001
0.7733129495624551 0.7500000000000001
0.03800607206261242 0.05000000000000001
0.7116353720754358 0.7500000000000001
0.01845039536391846 0.05000000000000001
0.3398936159178093 0.3500000000000001
0.44312359112375477 0.45000000000000007
0.3010799287710728 0.3500000000000001
0.37401793425303764 0.3500000000000001
0.7049621859196674 0.7500000000000001
0.5044002562214386 0.55
0.30073336035132303 0.3500000000000001
0.31630770524340746 0.3500000000000001
0.8465422342801152 0.8500000000000002
0.39679187879066746 0.3500000000000001
0.10910213537513935 0.15000000000000002
0.8932112016365839 0.8500000000000002
0.9858585971124458 0
0.49024772936880123 0.45000000000000007
(993 more)
```

```
import numpy as np

def phix(x,N):
    ncr = N**(1/3)
    lam = int(ncr)
    sumx = 0
    for i in range(lam):
        if i/ncr < x < (i+1)/ncr:
            sumx += (i+i+1) / (2*ncr)
    return sumx

N = 1000
x = np.random.random_sample(N)
for x1 in x:
    print( x1, phix(x1,N) )
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot `x_new=phix(x, N)` and `x_val = np.array(list(Counter(x_new).keys()))`? How to fix that?

Comment: But why?  You STILL haven't told us what you are trying to do.  What do you think that `x_val` would give you?  The `keys` of the `Counter` object would be the unique values.  Is that what you want?  You can do that by passing through a `set`.

Comment: That will tell me the probability of each value appears. The main goal is that I want to modify the function `adapW1_eot` defined here https://github.com/johanneswiesel/Wasserstein-correlation/blob/main/fig2.py. I try to rewrite `x_new` and `y_new`.

Comment: I think your code is not right? Can you please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016711/how-to-define-a-function-and-return-a-ndarray-format-value? I describe my question in more details. Thank you!

Comment: The KEYS will not tell you the probability.  The VALUES would, if you divided by the sum.  However, what's the point of this?  What you're have here is a bizarrely complicated rounding function.   A set of random numbers will product basically uniform probabilities.  What will you learn?